# Python pandas DataFrame, sum row's value which data is Tru

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to pandas and even new to programming.

I have DataFrame of [500 rows x 24 columns]

500 rows are rank of data and 24 columns are years and months.

What I want is

1. select data from df
2. get all data's row value by int
3. sum all row value

I did `DATAF = df1[df1.isin(['MYDATA'])]`

DATAF is something like below

```
    19_01 19_02 19_03 19_04 19_05
0     NaN  MYDATA NaN   NaN   NaN
1    MYDATA NaN  MYDATA NaN   NaN
2     NaN   NaN   NaN  MYDATA NaN
3     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

so I want to sum all the row value

which would be like 1 + 0 + 1 + 2

it would be nicer if sum is like 2 + 1 +2 + 3. because rows are rank of data

is there any way to do this?

Comment: By _row value_ do you mean the index? _rows are rank of data_ What do you mean by rank? It sounds like you should add an actual column for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
rows, cols = np.where(DATAF .notna())
# rows: array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)

print((rows+1).sum())
# 8
```